# Can I delete "NvApp-UpdateFramework" folder on Windows?

Tags: nvidia-geforce

I see `C:\ProgramData\NVIDIA Corporation\NvApp-UpdateFramework` takes 2.6 GB and I wonder if it's generated data and I can safely delete it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see:

[Nvidia](https://www.nvidia.com/en-us/geforce/forums/game-ready-drivers/13/)

and similar NVIDIA links.

Also see:

[More NVIDIA Information](https://www.minitool.com/news/how-uninstall-nvidia-drivers.html)

> You also need to go to the ProgramData/Program Files/Program Files
> (x86) folders to check whether there are NVIDIA folders. If yes, you
> can delete them when necessary

So, You can delete this folder as it is not critical to NVIDIA operation.

One safety concern:  Make sure all NVIDIA updates are complete.  Assuming so, you can delete the folder.

It will very most likely be re-created at the next NVIDIA update.

4 GB is not a big concern on my disk but it may be different for you